# Drupal 7 Theming From HTML to Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, theming

[image]

Here the wireframe of one of my pages.

1. I have already coded my pages with HTML, CSS and JS and now I want to integrate it into Drupal.
2. I want to do everything with code without working with Drupal's interface.
3. My project contains many pages so i want to know how to theme every page on the same directory.
4. My objectif is just to theme the website(static).

I want full and recommended steps to do this with details of you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect that someone will got trough your requests and tell you exactly what you have to do. Search the Web for some theming tutorials, learn how to do stuff and do it on your own. Ask if you have some specific problem.

```
http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-create-drupal-7-theme-scratch
    https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7?p=1151
    https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme
    https://www.drupal.org/theming
```